# Connections checking in c3p0 pool

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, socketexception

I'm developing with Java SE application using Hibernate 4 and c3p0 for communication with MariaDB database. It's long running application, waiting for signals from outside, so sometimes database closes my connections after 8 hours of inactivity. I tried to configure c3p0 connections validating but it's not working. Could you help me?

Error log (thrown during named query execution):

> ```
> 2014-10-27 08:10:19.062 ERROR [trans] com.example.runnable.T1 - Exception thrown during event processing, rollbacking transaction: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
>         at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
>         at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)                                                                                                                                                    
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)                                                                                                                                                                    
>         at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)                                                                                                                                                                         
>         at com.example.runnable.T1.find(EventsTransmitter.java:140)                                                                                                                         
>         at com.example.runnable.T1.run(EventsTransmitter.java:86)                                                                                                                                  
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)                                                                                                                                                                                             
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 108,132,692 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 108,132,692 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.                                                                                                                                                              
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor30.newInstance(Unknown Source)                                                                                                                                                            
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)                                                                                                                              
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)                                                                                                                                                                   
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)                                                                                                                                                                              
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)                                                                                                                                                         
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3661)                                                                                                                                                                                    
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2417)                                                                                                                                                                             
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)                                                                                                                                                                          
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)                                                                                                                                                                   
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)                                                                                                                                                     
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)                                                                                                                                                        
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)                                                                                                                                       
>         ... 17 more                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe                                                                                                                                                                                             
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)                                                                                                                                                                           
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>         at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
>         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3643)
>         ... 23 more
> ```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.33</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyBase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">30</property>

    <mapping class="com.example.domain.E" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

src/main/resources/c3p0-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c3p0-config>
    <default-config>
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">1800</property> <!-- 30 minutes -->
    </default-config>
</c3p0-config>
```

**Edited**

In logs on startup I'm getting c3p0 configuration (executing by Maven from Netbeans):

```
...
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@81187ff9
[ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@e1820e10 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000,
autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null,
connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null,
forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kflt95n558v5xddgsj|2cf3d63b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 1800, initialPoolSize -> 5,
maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 300, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 30,
maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@2f0d7eae [ description -> null, driverClass -> null,
factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> z8kflt95n558v5xddgsj|1e6a3214, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyBase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true,
properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> SELECT 1 FROM DUAL, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0,
testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ],
dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> z8kflt95n558v5xddgsj|7161d8d1, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
...
```

**Edit 2**

When executing jar created by maven-shade-plugin I'm getting:

> paź 27, 2014 10:56:22 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator
>   instantiateC3p0Provider WARN: HHH000022: c3p0 properties were
>   encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the
>   classpath; these properties are going to be ignored. paź 27, 2014
>   10:56:22 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) paź 27, 2014 10:56:22 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator

or when I tried to indicate `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider` in properties:

> INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider:
>   org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider Initial SessionFactory
>   creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
>   create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at com.example.util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:27)
>           at com.example.App.run(App.java:31)
>           at com.example.App.main(App.java:25)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
>   create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
>
> ```
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:261)
>
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
>
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
>
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>
>     at com.example.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
>
>     ... 2 more                                                                                                                                                                                                                Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate
> ```
>
> connection provider [org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
>
> ```
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:197)
>
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:120)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:55)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException:
> ```
>
> Unable to resolve name
>   [org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider] as strategy
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:194)
>           ... 16 more

But everything is good when starting by Maven. Unfortunately I need this to work from single jar. Any ideas why org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider cannot be found in shaded jar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, i managed to fix all problems. Here is soultion.

First of all, as Steve Waldman suggested, c3p0 wasn't actually initialized, but in Hibernate 4.3 `hibernate.connection.provider_class` parameter should be: `org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider`. In [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/c3p0/internal/C3P0ConnectionProvider.html) you can read:

> A connection provider that uses a C3P0 connection pool. Hibernate will
>   use this by default if the hibernate.c3p0.* properties are set.

But in my opinion it's good to put this parameter by yourself, and it's needed if you are using c3p0 config file, not `hibernate.c3p0.*` properties.

---

Second problem was obtaining session by calling `SessionFactory.openSession()` at the begining of the thread and later using always the same session object. I suppose after database connection was broken and there was new one recreated in pool, using old session caused using old, broken connection. So possible solutions were obtaining new session by `SessionFactory.openSession()` after catching connection error or using `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` at the begining of every communication. I've decided to use the second option (in this case my application waits for external signal, sometimes for hours, so I'm obtaining current session after each signal).

---

My final configuration:

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyBase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

c3p0-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c3p0-config>
    <default-config>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">5</property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">5</property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout">3000</property>
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection">30</property>

    <property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">300</property> <!-- 5 minutes -->
    </default-config>
</c3p0-config>
```

With this c3p0 configuration:

- Every 5 minutes of not performing any queries on connection it will be tested, so it will never be invalidated by DB (in standard configuration MySQL invalidates connection after 8 hours of inactivity),
- If DB will be restarted or connection(s) will be manually killed we have two options:
  a) after max 5 minutes connections will be reestablished,
  b) if application tries to perform query before automatic connection reestablishing `HibernateException` will be thrown, then connection will be reestablished and next query will succeed.

Optionally `testConnectionOnCheckout` could be set to true to prevent exceptions, but it will cause performance troubles (see [documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing)).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting testConnectionOnCheckout to true in your c3p0-config.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure c3p0 is actually initialized, and that it has the config you expect it to have?

in your logs, at INFO level, you should see a dump of your c3p0 DataSource's config upon pool initialization. verify that it is there, and that it is the configuration you expect.

if it is not there, please consider adding the following line to your hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
```

Comment: You are right, c3p0 was not initialized when I'm executing my fat jar from console - see updated question. I found out that in hibernate-c3p0 package v4.3.6 there is no org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider class, but there is org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider instead. I used it and it looks good, c3p0 is initialized, I'm only waiting to check if problem with connections checking is resolved.