# could not connect to server database in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am able to connect to my local db using `hibernate`, but I couldn't connect to my remote server db which is `mysql`. I am getting this error:

```
 Initial SessionFactory creation
 failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create
 requested service
 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
 org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
 service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:261)
    at
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at
 com.axelta.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:31)
    at com.axelta.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)    at
 com.axelta.service.AxServiceImpl.getHeartbeatEnabledDevicesList(AxServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.axelta.Scheduler.heartBeatMainService(Scheduler.java:19)     at
 com.axelta.Scheduler.main(Scheduler.java:38) Caused by:
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection
 provider [org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider]     at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:197)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:120)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:55)
    at
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
    at
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    ... 15 more Caused by:
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException:
 Unable to resolve name
 [org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider] as strategy
 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]     at
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
    at
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:194)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Please mention about mysql version and the local database. Is it mysql or In memory database like H2 ? Share the connection properties and driver details

Comment: please share your hibernate configuration file.

Comment: it is mysql 5.1

Comment: Please share configuration and your attempts to fix the problem.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710117/2987755

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- Database Settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <!-- for org.hibernate.dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10 </property>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxDeviceDetails"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxAlarm"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxAlarmType"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxClient"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxClientGroup"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxDeviceMaster"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxNodeAlarm"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxNodeAlarmUsers"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxNodeDetails"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxNodeMetadataDefinition"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxRules"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.AxUser"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.HeartBeat"/>
    <mapping class="com.axelta.model.Sim"/>

</session-factory>
```

Comment: Should this be an answer to your question? Or did you mean to edit your initial question?

Comment: Then please edit your question, and delete this answer. Otherwise it's confusing for users.